# Python parse then put in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with a data like this:

```
------------------------------
------------------------------
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10>

------
++++++
%%RequestHandler
    DATA1 = 123456
    ERROR1 = 500
    DATA2 = 56789
    ERROR2 = 505

Count = 4
---
```

I would like to create a dataframe like

| DATA1 | ERROR1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 500 |
| 56789 | 505 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another regex approach with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
import re

                                                         # or file.read()
out = (pd.DataFrame(re.findall(r'^\s+(\w+)(\d+) = (\d+)', text, flags=re.M))
         .pivot(index=1, columns=0, values=2)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
     DATA ERROR
1  123456   500
2   56789   505
```

Used input:

```
text = '''------------------------------
------------------------------
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10>

------
++++++
%%RequestHandler
    DATA1 = 123456
    ERROR1 = 500
    DATA2 = 56789
    ERROR2 = 505

Count = 4'''
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkuI0t/1)

Comment: I slightly changed the regex and added a link to demonstrate how it works if you need to adapt it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that you want, you can regular expressions to extract desired data from raw structured text file:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

# Read the file
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()

# Use regular expressions to extract the values
data = re.findall(r"DATA\d+\s*=\s*(\d+)", content)
error = re.findall(r"ERROR\d+\s*=\s*(\d+)", content)

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATA": data, "ERROR": error})
print(df)
```

Example:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

content = '''
------------------------------
------------------------------
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10> 
<TIME:2020-01-01 01:25:10>

------
++++++
%%RequestHandler
    DATA1 = 123456
    ERROR1 = 500
    DATA2 = 56789
    ERROR2 = 505

Count = 4
---
'''

data = re.findall(r"DATA\d+\s*=\s*(\d+)", content)
error = re.findall(r"ERROR\d+\s*=\s*(\d+)", content)

df = pd.DataFrame({"DATA": data, "ERROR": error})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     DATA ERROR
0  123456   500
1   56789   505
```

Comment: Not exactly what he wants I don't think. I think you'd just need to tweak the regex to look for DATA, rather than DATA1. I think the col headings in the OP's expected output are confusing.

Comment: works fine. thank you @OmidRoshani, TaxpayersMoney